# Equivalent linear inequalities system - Coefficients bound?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities, gm.general-mathematics

Just having some difficulties with this system of inequalities...

We know *E* is a system of **m** linear inequalities of the form:

a<sub>1</sub>,<sub>1</sub>x<sub>1</sub>+ ··· +a<sub>1</sub>,<sub>n</sub>x<sub>n</sub> ≤ b<sub>1</sub>

...

a<sub>m</sub>,<sub>1</sub>x<sub>1</sub>+ ··· +a<sub>m</sub>,<sub>n</sub>x<sub>n</sub> ≤ b<sub>m</sub>

And *E'* an equivalent system, derived from *E*:

a'<sub>1</sub>,<sub>2</sub>x<sub>2</sub>+ ··· +a'<sub>1</sub>,<sub>n</sub>x<sub>n</sub> ≤ b'<sub>1</sub>

...

a'<sub>m</sub>,<sub>2</sub>x<sub>2</sub>+ ··· +a'<sub>m</sub>,<sub>n</sub>x<sub>n</sub> ≤ b'<sub>m</sub>

I have proven that given that if *E* has a solution, then so does *E'* and vice-versa, on the set of *R* (real numbers). However, now we suppose that the coefficients *a<sub>i</sub><sub>j</sub>* and *b<sub>i</sub>* in the original system *E* are in fact integers with a maximum absolute value M.

Since the coefficients in the system *E* are integers, then the various coefficients in the system *E'* will be rational numbers, and so can be written in the form *a/b*, where *a* is the numerator and *b* the denominator.

How can I obtain a bound on the absolute values of these numerators and denominators as a function of M? I'm not quite sure which would be the right approach in order to correctly prove it..

Thanks for taking your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such bound.  Let's consider the simplest case: a single inequality in one variable:

$$a x \le b$$

For any $c > 0$ this is equivalent to

$$ c a x \le c b$$

But since $c$ is arbitrary, there is no way to bound numerator or denominator of $|c a|$ or $|c b|$.

Comment: Perhaps we were meant to assume that, in each inequality, the numerators of the rationals are relatively prime, likewise the denominators.